# Inconsistent mediation in my mediation model

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, mediation, path-model

The direct effect of WE is 0.758; while the indirect effect is -.19; that leads to total effect of .46.....I need to know as inconsistent mediation means opposite signs between direct and indirect effect but both effects do not cancel out. So, can i say there exist no suppression.

Answer (score 1):

Mediation is not a dichotomy - that is, it isn't "present" or "not present".  Rather, it is a continuum from "none at all" to "a lot".

In your case, there is considerable mediation.  The mediation reduces the effect by more than 1/4.

Comment: Do i report that mediation reduces the effect? what about research support there is paucity of this phenomenon

Comment: Yes, you can report that mediation reduces the effect.  I don't know anything about the research in the area.